# thead not showing in HTML email

Tags: html, email

I'm coding my own HTML email using a Mailchimp template. I have a thead for 2 tables and they look fine in a webpage, but they are not rendering in Mailchimp or in any test email platforms (Gmail, Apple Mail, Outlook 365 etc). It simply just omits the entire thead block. Why is my thead not showing up?

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnTextContentContainer" 
width="100%" style="min-width: 100% !important;background-color: 
#FFFFFF;">                                                               
    <thead>
       <tr>                                                   
       <th bgcolor="#f2f2f2" valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" 
          style="padding: 18px;color: #F2F2F2;font-family: Poppins, 
          Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;text-
          align: center;">

         <span style="font-size:18px; color:#000000; text-
          align:center;"><strong>Shipping Information</strong></span>

        </th>
        </tr>                                                                
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if you look at it in gmail, etc and you inspect it, is the thead element there or does it get removed completely? debugging mail templates is a pita, if you just change th to td, does it work? also try removing all styles and only use the th element, this should work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal best practices, semantics and other guidelines catered around HTML go out the door when it comes to HTML emails. MailChimp has an [Email Design Reference](https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/html/) you should read along with [other related resources](https://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/) around how to structure and compose your HTML emails.

For your specific use-case, simply omit the optional table elements such as `<thead>` and `<tbody>`:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnTextContentContainer" width="100%" style="min-width: 100% !important;background-color: #FFFFFF;">                                                               
    <tr>                                                   
        <th bgcolor="#f2f2f2" valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 18px;color: #F2F2F2;font-family: Poppins, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;text-align: center;">
            <span style="font-size:18px; color:#000000; text-
      align:center;"><strong>Shipping Information</strong></span>
        </th>
    </tr>                                                                
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `<caption>` instead of `<thead>` and it's working. Thanks!